# Salvar console.log em algum arquivo

Tags: node.js

Salvar console.log em algum arquivo específico

Existe algum módulo que salva a saída do `console.log()` em algum arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui.

```
const { Console } = require('console')
const fs = require('fs')


const logger = new Console({
stdout: fs.createWriteStream("log.txt")
})

logger.log("Texto")
```